# How to navigate through Vaadin grid and select/edit an item using keyboard?

Tags: java, vaadin, grid-layout, vaadin14

I'd like to be able to navigate around a grid in Vaadin 14 (or higher) with only Keyboard shortcuts. It's possible to select a single cell in the grid, but then it's only visually selected and i can't find out which one is currently selected through code.
I found this question here:
[How to navigate through Vaadin grid and select an item using keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47302398/how-to-navigate-through-vaadin-grid-and-select-an-item-using-keyboard)

This would solve my problem but this Add-on is for Vaadin 8 and doesn't work with version 14.

Is there either any way to find out which cell is currently selected (on another button press) or is there any other Add-on i haven't found, which does basically the same but for Vaadin 14?

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
I did not understand at first that you are in fact not yet properly selecting an item, instead it probably only shifts the `focus` around.
I believe you can select the focused row by pressing `space` key. I tested it [over here](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-grid/java-examples/selection) and seems to work out of the box.
For GridMultiSelectionModel it looks like you need to have the focus on the selection column.

You can [define your own shortcut](https://vaadin.com/docs/v13/flow/components/tutorial-flow-shortcut.html#adding-custom-shortcuts) if space is not what you want. However, in that case I don't know the answer to "how do you find out which row is currently focused?". maybe something along the lines of this? (no guarantees)

```
UI.getCurrent().addShortcutListener((event) -> grid.select(event.getSource()), Key.ENTER);
```

Comment: Sorry if the question wasn't clear enough. Yes, you are right the focus is shifting around and when I then press space, i can read out at which row I'm currently at. But I don't want to press space every time i shifted around. Another way to ask this questions is: How can I automatically select the current row where the user shifted to. Is there a way to press the space key automatically (programatically)?

Comment: With shifting I mean shifting the `focus` around.